# How to created a sorted DropDown from an ObservableCollection?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, dropdown, devexpress-wpf

How do I ensure that an ObservableCollection is always sorted?

---

#### WPF

I have an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> Rows { get; private set; }
```

I have a dropdown in a grid that displays the `Name` property in `MyViewModel` (this is `DevExpress`):

```
<dxg:GridColumn x:Name="PortwareName" Header="Destination Id" FieldName="Rows" MinWidth="200">
    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
       <dxe:ComboBoxEditSettings AutoComplete="True" 
                                ValueMember="Name" 
                                DisplayMember="Name" 
                                FilterCondition="Contains"
                                IncrementalFiltering="True"
                                ImmediatePopup="True" 
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Rows}" />
    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

#### Disclaimer

I have no relation to DevExpress (Infragistics is great also), and the dropdown could also use a generic WPF control.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `ICollectionView` wrapper over the collection, then change the property in the XAML to `ItemsSource={Binding Path=RowsSorted}"`:

```
private ICollectionView _rowsSorted;

public ICollectionView RowsSorted
{
  get
  {
    if (_rowsSorted == null)
    {
      _rowsSorted = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Rows);
      _rowsSorted.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
    return _rowsSorted;
  }
}
```

The collection will be sorted by the property `Name` in the `Rows` class.

### Other Solutions?

There are many other solutions, most of them involving special observable collections which remain sorted no matter what is added to them. However, I've found that adding this "wrapper" collection just works, and has no hidden corner cases.

### Why adding a wrapper does nothing more than obfuscation...

Here is another solution. However, you will observe that the wrapper code does not add much value:

- It doesn't really decrease the amount of typing much.
- It does a nice job of obscuring what's actually happening.
- It is proprietary, so other people can't read your code easily.
- Not recommended.

The code:

```
/// <summary>
///     Intent: Wrapper over a sorted collection.
/// </summary>
/// <demo>
/*
// Demo of how to wrap a sorted ObservableCollection over an existing one.
private SortedObservableCollection<MyViewModel> _rowsSorted;

public ICollectionView PortwareBrokerDropdownListSorted
{
    get
    {
        if (_rowsSorted == null)
        {
            // Rows is the original observable collection.
            _rowsSorted = new SortedObservableCollection<MyViewModel>(Rows, "Name");
        }
        return _rowsSorted.Value;
    }
}
*/
/// </demo>
public class SortedObservableCollection<T>
{
    private readonly ObservableCollectionSmart<T> _sourceCollection;
    private readonly string _fieldName;

    public SortedObservableCollection(ObservableCollectionSmart<T> sourceCollection, string fieldName)
    {
        _sourceCollection = sourceCollection;
        _fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    private ICollectionView _rowsSorted;

    public ICollectionView Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (_rowsSorted == null)
            {
                _rowsSorted = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_sourceCollection);
                _rowsSorted.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(_fieldName, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            }
            return _rowsSorted;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you ask and answer your own question?

Comment: @RickS it's specifically allowed and encouraged for those who want to share knowledge.  The question has to be a valid question, of course, and this one is.  OP here has presented a number of methods for sorting the collection, which can be helpful for folks encountering the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public iEnumerable<MyViewModel> SortedObservableCollection 
{
    get { return Rows.OrderBy(x => x.Name); }
}
```

you can do CollectionViewSource in XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <src:Places x:Key="places"/>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{StaticResource places}" x:Key="cvs" IsLiveSorting="True">
      <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="CityName"/>
      </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: That won't work, as the UI won't know to refresh if `Rows` changes.

Comment: @Will OK.   Are you sure private ICollectionView _rowsSorted; will change?  I have made updates work by calling Notify on SortedObservableCollection.

Comment: That's the part lacking from your answer.  Yep, if you raise PropertyChanged passing in "SortedObservableCollection" as the property name, it would definitely work.  All you'd have to do would be subscribed to the CollectionChanged event and invoke it within the event handler.